# In Linux, free blocks(free pages) are related to the file system?

Tags: linux, memory, filesystems, xen

I want to aggregate free pages to remove duplicated pages from XEN image.

Before saving, I collected free pages by using zone free_list array.

But after restoring, Linux occurred Bad page panic.

```
init[1]: segfault at 2b ip 00007ffad1220329 sp 00007fffb125ad8 error 4 in init[7ffad1211000+ec000]
init: Caught segmentation fault, core dumped
```

I know maybe I can't get solution from this question.

could you expect why does that errors occur?

And I wondered free blocks are related to file system (i.e ext4)

Anybody give some advices to me?

Thank you.